# Value not equal to &nbsp OR value not eqal to space in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to detect `space` in jquery ? How to check a value equal to space or `&nbsp` in jquery ?

Please check this code .

```
 Search:  <input type="text" name="search-filter" class="search-filter" / > 
          <input type="submit" value="submit" class="search-img" >

$(".search-img").on("click",function(){
    var search_val=$(".search-filter").val();

     if(search_val!=="" && search_val!==null ){

         alert(search_val);

      }
});
```

Here when i just enter a space and click submit button it is alerting .

Why this code is not working ?

Comment: Try checking for `" "` rather than for just `""`

Comment: Why are you testing for `null`? The `.val()` method will never return `null` for an input element. It wouldn't return `"&nbsp;"` either, unless the user literally typed those six characters.

Comment: this is new information for me friend. From where you got this information ?

Comment: I read the documentation for that method as provided on the jQuery website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [.trim()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to remove white spaces from beginning and end of the string. Try this:

```js
$(".search-img").on("click",function(){
    var search_val=$(".search-filter").val().trim();
     if(search_val!=="" && search_val!==null){
         alert(search_val);
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Search:  <input type="text" name="search-filter" class="search-filter" / > 
          <input type="submit" value="submit" class="search-img" >
```

Comment: what happen if my input value is red product ? . In this case i need to search as red product in MySQL i don't want to trim this value to redproduct because in mysql i stored as red product .

Comment: `.trim()` will work becuase it will remove white spaces from beginning and end of the string. If you enter `red product` after using `.trim()` value will be `red product` only.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
search_val.trim()
```

It  removes any leading and trailing spaces from the string

Answer (score 0):

You are using a submit type which means that if you want to catch the event you should add event.preventDefault() to your jQuery code. Also, you are going to alert for a search_val different from " " and null.

```
$(".search-img").on("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var search_val=$(".search-filter").val();

     if(search_val!==" " && search_val!==null ){

         alert(search_val);

      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(search_val!==" " && search_val!==null ){

         alert(search_val);

      }
```

OR

```
if(search_val!=" " && search_val!==null ){

         alert(search_val);

      }
```